# devise token auth token creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, token, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there any way of executing a method after token creation in devise_token_auth? The code I am working with takes the generated token, encrypts it and stores it in another api. The current code works, but it only takes the last token generated instead of the current token. As the current method is being executed after session creation instead of token creation. 
The code I trying am to execute:

```
class SessionsController < DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController
  require "uri"
    require "net/http"

  after_action :authorization, only: [:create]

  def authorization
    token = request.headers["access-token"]
    encrypted_token = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(token)
    client = request.headers["client"]
    params = { "token": encrypted_token, "client": client }

    Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse("http://localhost:3001/api_keys"), params)
    puts params
    puts "AUTHORIZATION"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController` like the normal `Devise` controllers uses the idiom:

```
module DeviseTokenAuth
  class SessionsController < DeviseTokenAuth::ApplicationController
    # ...
    def create
      # ...
      yield @resource if block_given?
    end
  end
end
```

This lets subclasses "tap" into the flow of the method.

```
class SessionsController < DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController
  def create
    super do |resource|
      # this is executed after the resource is saved but before the response is sent.
    end
  end
end
```

If thats not the point you want you need to create your own implementation of create since the code is inlined.